# Regex to check/set a price with dot/comma and parse into a Integer

Tags: java, javascript, regex, groovy, integer

I want to accept prices and convert to integers like:

```
    1.400 -> true, "$1.400,00" , 140000
    1.400,00 -> true, "$1.400,00" , 140000
    1.400,0 or 1.400,000000 -> true, "$1.400,00" , 140000
//get only the first 2 digits before the comma ->1.400,9394239 -> 1.400,93
    1.400.000 -> true, "$1.400.000,00", 140000000
    1.400.00 -> false
    1.40.00 -> false

    14,00 -> true, "$14,00" , 1400
    14 -> true, "$14,00" , 1400
    14.00 -> false
```

Information: My project is in groovy.

If possible I would like to solve this problem because I've got a project that doesn`t use Double to deal with prices, it converts to Integers after treat the String just like that but in javascript, I understand some parts of the code but I don't know how to implement in groovy/java, but I`ll paste it anyway.

```
String.prototype.formatNumber = function() {
    var value = this.replace(",",".").replace(/[^\d\.]/g,'');
    value = 0+value;
    while (isNaN(value))
        value = value.substring(0,valor.length-1);
    value = parseInt(value * 100) / 100;
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check it against this regex first:

`^(\d?\d?\d?\.?)*(,\d+)?$`

And if it matches, then replace all the periods (`.`) to blank, and split at the comma (`,`).